# Flash OpenWrt Routers from Telnet

Tags: ssh, openwrt, router, telnet

I have two routers. One has Chaos Calmer and the other has Attitude Adjustment. When I turn them on and check arp, nothing comes up. When I check route, the hardware address says (incomplete) but the IP address is showing up.

So, I restarted my routers and hit the reset button and was able to telnet into the routers. I can't ssh into them.

**When telnet starts**

- It says root@(none) instead of root@openwrt
- My network and wireless files are missing.
- When I try to run opkg, I get this error:

  ```
  opkg_conf_load: Could not create lock file /var/lock/opkg.lock: No such file or directory.
  ```

**Questions**

I've been searching online and there are a lot of different possibilities for what could be wrong (i.e. bugs with opkg, bad configs, etc.). I just think I'm going to flash the router.

- Is `root@(none)` an indicator that I am in failsafe mode?
- How can I flash the router without `opkg` not working? Opkg has documentation, but the page says there are a lot of errors with the documentation. So, does anyone have a tried method that they have used. (I have an offline copy of attitude adjustment and chaos calmer though from my original download)
- Is there a link between the (incomplete) hardware address and the `opkg` problem? I'm guessing yes, but I didn't want to assume.

I'd appreciate any help, suggestions, advice, etc. for any of these points.

Thanks you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for an answer on this extremely old question: If the router is in failsafe, you need to mount_root before anything else, and then change the password.  Telnet access sticks until the password is changed to something other than the default (blank).